# Roo::Spreadsheet.open の読み取り専用オプション

Tags: ruby, excel

`Roo`を使い`.xls`のファイルを開こうとしたら下記のようなエラーが出ました。

```
roo = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(open(file))
[DEPRECATION] extend Roo::Tempdir and use its .make_tempdir instead
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/ironsand/foo.xls
from /var/www/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spreadsheet-1.1.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:73:in `initialize'
```

ファイルのパーミッションを確認したら`444`で読み込み専用だったので`644`に変更して読み直したら正常に読み込めました。

ただ、読み取りしか必要のない処理なので読み取り専用モードがあればそうしたいのですが、そのようなオプションはありますか？

Comment: roo-xls package のソースコードを眺めると、ファイルオープンモードのデフォルトが `rb+` になっていますので、`roo = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, mode: 'r')` とすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 試してみましたが `Permission denied` になってしまいました。`mode`オプションを受け付けていないみたいですね。

Comment: 参考までに、`ruby 2.3.3/roo-2.7.1/roo-xls-1.0.0` で試した限りではエラーは発生しませんでした。

Comment: ああ、すいません。`Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, mode: 'r')`ではなく`Roo::Spreadsheet.open(open(file, mode: 'r'))`としてしまっていたのが原因でした。教えて頂いた方法で無事に開けました。